# WIC - Exif Metadata Query - How to get image description

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, exif, wic

I have an image that has some French characters in the "Image Description" exif metadata field.

I m doing this (where reader is a IWICMetadataQueryReader* and value a PROPVARIANT):

```
reader->GetMetadataByName(L"/app1/ifd/{ushort=270}", &value);
if (value.vt == VT_LPSTR) result = value.pszVal;
```

and the result is **"c'est l'Ã©tÃ©"** instead of **"c'est l'été"**

How can I query so that it's a VT_LPWSTR instead, or any other way to get the correct string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using CA2W like so

```
CA2W convertToUTF8(value.pszVal, CP_UTF8);
result = convertToUTF8.m_psz;
```